# Getting the character at given coordinate in C++

Tags: c++

How can I get the character at a specific coordinate in C++? 
Is it possible to use `gotoxy()` for that coordinate and then read the character using some function?

Comment: Are you just trying to read the character from a given point on the screen regardless of the application that text is hosted in? Expand on your question so we know what you're trying to really do.

Comment: In case you just want specific character from entered string: `std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); std::cout << line[pos];` ...

Comment: We don't know what exactly is that you are trying to do. We don't know the context of the problem and neither you have shown us any attempt of yours or at least some existing code where this is needed...

Comment: Yes I want to read the character for a given point on the screen after a number of outputs. Is that possible? And I'm not quite sure what "application" means but I'm using Turbo C++ if that helps anyway. Actually what I'm doing is trying to make the snake game without using a 2-D array, so doing it would require getting character on the screen to make the snake move.

Comment: Which environment are you trying to run in?  Is this Linux, Windows, Android, ???

Comment: I'm working in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, **standard C++** has no concept of displays.  Displays could be raster or ray tracing or anything else.

There are console programs and windowing applications that use the screen. So, we need more information about your platform.

When a program "prints" to the screen, the characters are translated into bitmaps using fonts and stored in the graphics memory.  The graphics memory has no concept of characters or shapes, just plain old dots.

Also, the coordinates on a display change, depending on pixel size, pixel density and pixel depth (value / color).  For example, a character bitmap may be green or blue or be larger.

So, to retrieve the character at a given point in the display memory, you would have to determine where the point is (is it even in a font bitmap) and then try to use some kind of OCR to determine the character, font, and pitch (font height).

So, there may be some function to do this.  Search the web.  There is not one in any standard C++ library.

Comment: What if I'm working in graphics mode, can I make images of characters and compare them with the one on screen? Though what I'm trying to do has to be done in textmode, but is it possible in graphics mode atleast?

Comment: Read up on Optical Character Recognition (OCR).  What you ask may be more difficult than you perceive.  You should be able to retrieve a bitmap from the Display Memory and compare it to another {font} bitmap.  Given a fixed point ASCII character set, that's 128 bitmaps you have to compare with; or at least bitmaps of your characters.  Remember, if one or more pixels are out of place, it won't be exactly equal.

Comment: Also, bitmaps for italic, underlined, strikeout and bold will not match bitmaps for plain characters.

Answer (score 0):

[Curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Can Curses library tell you what letter is at a given position on the terminal?  My understanding is the Curses is an output only package.